# Contact number in HTML Form

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-5, contact-form

if we uses "tel" in input then we can give max or min length for the input but its drawback is it may take all kind of inputs whether it is numeric or alphabets,

And if we uses "number" for input then it takes only number but we can not give it min-max characters limit.

Even though I have mentioned pattern inside it but no change.
So is there any alternate for the same to give max-min length and can take only numeric?

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="exampleFormControlInput3">Mobile Number</label>
        <div class="input-group">
           <span class="input-group-text" id="basic-addon1">+91</span>
               <input type="tel" class="form-control" id="exampleFormControlInput3" maxlength="10" placeholder="012-345-6789" pattern="[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{3}">
        </div> 
 </div>
```

[image]

Note: I have used bootstrap5 for the same.

Comment: **You should be using `type="tel"`**. Telephone numbers can and do contain letters, so that's why it's permitted. **Do not** use `type="number"` for a phone-number because _phone-numbers are not integers_: they're strings (just with a confusing name).

Comment: Also, phone numbers can and do contain punctuation characters as well, e.g. `+1 (425) 123-4567` or `+44 (0)7999 123456`, as well as using the letter `x`  to denote an extension number, e.g. `+1 (425) 123-4567 x 123`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You using input type tel and can make a mix with javascript if you want avoid completely alphabetic characters. The type tel provides pattern to but it validate afterwards. And not every browser will supported.

```html
<label for="phone">Enter your phone number:</label>

<input type="tel" id="phone" name="phone"
       maxlength ="6"
       pattern="[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{3}"
       oninput="this.value = this.value.replace(/[^0-9.]/g, '').replace(/(\..*?)\..*/g, '$1');"
       required>

<small>Format: 123-456</small>
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/tel

Comment: Is there any option to do with css, bootstrap and html only?

Comment: @AlapJoshi unfortunately is not possible. You have problems to implementing or why you asking?

Comment: Actually I know only html, css and bootstrap, that's the reason behind that.

Answer (score -1):

Semantically using `type="number"` is incorrect. You *should* be only using `type='tel'`. If you want fine control over what the user inputs, you should be using a pattern for that.

```
<input type="tel" id="phone" name="phone"
       pattern="[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{4}"
       required>
```

Read this doc, https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/tel

Comment: `type='number' min='8' max='12'` does not constrain the length to 8-to-12-chars: it means you can't enter "`13`" as a value, which is silly. Also, using a `pattern=""` is unwise because the OP's form has a country-code sub-field, and every country has its own different number pattern (and your `pattern` is a rough approximation of the `+1` NANP pattern, whereas the OP is likely in India `+91`); and people in a hurry will just type-in digits on their num-pad without punctuation, so using `pattern` validation with phone-number inputs is just annoying and slows-down (and frustrates!) users.

Comment: @Dai okay. but isnt the country code in another `select`?

Comment: Yes, but if the user selects a different country-code then the `pattern=""` would need to be updated with it, which requires JavaScript to work (_and_ that there's no bugs in that part of the JS), so it's instantly broken for non-JS users which is why I think it's a bad idea because it can't gracefully degrade. And it still doesn't solve the problem of now having to _force_ users to enter data-in to _exactly_ match the format, which is far from user-friendly.